# RESTful in Android. Do I need an additional library?

Tags: android, rest, http

I've been researching which way should my app connect with a REST server to make GET and POST actions and many people mention libraries like Volley, RetroFit, RESTdroid... while others just use HttpGet and HttpPost classes included in Android. User has to wait till this GET and POST actions to continue using the app, but these are done individually. What advantages have the libraries? Do I really need one? Android development and working with REST are new things for me, so even the question could sound weird, I don't know.

Comment: By default android provide built-in class to handle your RESTful services so need for other library and those all custom library provide some more feature or easily usability of some requirement so you can also use one of the custom library if is match you requirement.

Comment: If this is your first time handling network request, you should really try to do it on your own, write some network classes! Otherwise have a look at retrofit, it is a great restful lib for android.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Do I really need one?**
***No.***

**What advantages have the libraries?**
In general, the libraries will make it easier, simpler to focus on your task and what you want to achieve from/through the API calls.

These libraries provide you a network layer to work with where you only have to focus on request, its parameters and the response. You can handle errors directly as they return error information, if any, with the response. So, you can work with overriden functions and manage the exception handling in an easier way.
The callbacks would make your simple.

**Eg.**
[Android Asynchronous Http Client](http://loopj.com/android-async-http/)

> ```
> AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
> client.get("http://www.google.com", new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
>
>     @Override
>     public void onStart() {
>         // called before request is started
>     }
>
>     @Override
>     public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] response) {
>         // called when response HTTP status is "200 OK"
>     }
>
>     @Override
>     public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] errorResponse, Throwable e) {
>         // called when response HTTP status is "4XX" (eg. 401, 403, 404)
>     }
>
>     @Override
>     public void onRetry(int retryNo) {
>         // called when request is retried
>   }
> });
> ```

Here you have enough functions being overridden and ready for you to use it. You don't have to manage  the default http connections.  On the other hand, a [DefaultHttpClient](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/impl/client/DefaultHttpClient.html) would work well for you if you have your own end-to-end client server setup and if you absolutely need to know everything going on with your network layer.

It is good to write a custom one, extending the default, just to know how it all works. You can move on to the libraries any time you want.

Answer (score 1):

You can indeed write your own network layer, this might be a good idea if you want the practice and to understand how the network classes in Android work.

Alternatively there are many libraries that will abstract away all the boilerplate code and provide you with simple error handling, retry configuration etc.

This will allow you to concentrate on other parts of the app. You needn't ever touch the network or parsing code if you don't want to e.g. use Volley to make the requests and bind the JSON response to your object using GSON for presentation in a ListView.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use this project as library:

https://github.com/matessoftwaresolutions/AndroidHttpRestService

It's extremely easy and I use it for all my projects! It's under continous improvement...

I've developed it, so you can fell free of asking whatever you need!!

I hope it helps!!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need an additional library, but these libraries can greatly simplify common boilerplate related to such operations such as scheduling, caching, error handling, etc. It's also common, when working with a specific RESTful API, to have a high-level library that talks in terms of the API's functionality rather than in terms of raw HTTP requests. Some of these higher-level wrappers are hand-written while others, such as those used with APIs implemented with Google Cloud Endpoints, are automatically generated.

(Side note: since you mentioned that the user has to wait, you really should design your application such that the user is not waiting... use a SyncAdapter to prefetch data before the user asks for it and to upload local copies of data that still need to be written back to the Cloud wherever possible rather than immediately issuing requests in response to the user's actions unless it cannot be avoided).

Answer (score 0):

I mostly used Spring's Android project for RESTful services in android because I'm familiar with spring from different projects. However, I can also suggest that volley and loopj are also good choices for handling RESTful services in Android.

1. [Spring Android](http://projects.spring.io/spring-android/)
2. [Volley](http://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html)
3. [loopj](http://loopj.com/android-async-http/)

I hope these libraries could help you in your project!

Answer (score 0):

There are a many REST libraries available.These libraries basically tend to make your life easier. By easier,i mean that during network operations we encounter a lot of responses from the server like a 404, 200 etc. , these libraries basically already have an implementation to handle these responses, so that we don't have to worry about them. Some of them also queue your requests, in case, you have multiple requests to server etc.

I personally feel like if you want to completely understand about what is going on inside your application, try doing it without the libraries...you surely will have better grip of the application, but that requires efforts.

You may use Volley, it has got nice caching feature, but isn't that good with POST.

Retrofit is good.